# Different Title for Different Radio buttons in Cakephp form helper

Tags: cakephp, radio-button, form-helpers

How can i give different title for different radio button using CakePHP Form Helper

```
$radio_options = array('unknown'=>'Unknown','negative'=>'Negative','positive'=>'Positive');

$titles = array('0'=>'Unknown','1'=>'Negative','2'=>'Positive');
```

I am trying to create radio buttons like this

```
 echo $this->Form->input('radio_buttons', array(
                                    'options' => $radio_options,
                                    'legend' =>false,
                                    'label' => true,
                                    'div'=>false,
                                    'class'=>'radio inline',
                                    'type' => 'radio',
                                    'separator'=>'<br>',
                                    'title'=>$titles,));
```

But its not working..Form Helper creating same title for all of the radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what the FormHelper generates, then generate it manually or with a php foreach loop or something.

There are cases like this, when it's just easier (or the only way) to not use a helper.